There are no warnings and errors in my code but yet i am getting this error
Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
I am expecting the program to run.
